# My worker threads are not being picked up

Tags: node.js, typescript, multithreading

I'm implementing worker threads in my Node/Typescript application. Now I've come quite far except for the fact that it seems my worker threads are not being picked up/executed. I've added some loggers inside function which should be executed by the worker thread, but for some reason it doesn't show.

I'm calling a function to create a worker. Like this:

```
create_worker("./src/core/utils/worker.js", {
        term: "amsterdam",
        search_grid: chunked_maps_service![i],
        path: "../../adapters/worker.ts",
})
```

And this is the function to create a worker:

```
import { Worker } from "worker_threads";

const create_worker = (file: string, workerData: {}) =>
  new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker(file, {
      workerData: workerData,
    });

    worker.on("message", resolve);
    worker.on("error", reject);
    worker.on("exit", (code) => {
      if (code !== 0)
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
    });
  });

export default create_worker;
```

Because I'm using typescript I need to compile the typescript code to javascript code to make the worker understand it: Like this:

```
const path = require("path");
const { workerData } = require("worker_threads");

require("ts-node").register();
require(path.resolve(__dirname, workerData.path));
```

And then this is the function which should be executed in the worker thread:

```
import { parentPort } from "worker_threads";

async function worker() {
  console.log("started");
  parentPort.postMessage("fixed!");
}
```

Is there anything I'm forgetting?

Comment: What is `require(path.resolve(__dirname, workerData.path));` supposed to do? Create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It imports the typescript file. That typescript file is then compiled to javascript code which can be used by the worker. I updated the question a bit.

Comment: You don't show anything that calls the `worker()` function in your worker code module.

Comment: I updated the question so it makes more sense. My mistake.

Comment: You still don't show anything that actually calls the `worker()` function.  If that's all there is in the worker, then this is just a function definition with nothing that calls it so it never executes.

Comment: I'm passing the url of the worker.js file to the new Worker() invocation. There's also the path in the workerData object literal. That's the URL of the typescript file which has to be executed by the worker. You don't 'call' the work function. That's not how worker_threads work. When you invoke a new Worker class object, the function you provide should be executed immediately.

Comment: *When you invoke a new Worker class object, the function you provide should be executed immediately.* - no

Comment: @jfriend00, I just saw what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @Konrad, being a bit more descriptive would be nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't ever calling the function in your worker.

This code in the worker:

```
import { parentPort } from "worker_threads";

async function worker() {
  console.log("started");
  parentPort.postMessage("fixed!");
}
```

Just defines a function named `worker`.  It never calls that function.

If you want it called immediately, then you must call it like this:

```
import { parentPort } from "worker_threads";

async function worker() {
  console.log("started");
  parentPort.postMessage("fixed!");
}

worker();
```

FYI, in the worker implementations I've built, I usually either execute something based on data passed into the worker or the worker executes something based on a message it receives from the parent.